# Klov Report- Where to view the generated report in mongo DB

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have configured Klov reporter as follows

```
  private static ExtentReports _extentReport;
  private static KlovReporter _klovReporter;
  private static ExtentTest _currentTest;

 _extentReport = new ExtentReports();
 _klovReporter = new KlovReporter();
 _klovReporter.InitMongoDbConnection("localhost", 27017);
 _klovReporter.ProjectName = "CsharpReports";
 _klovReporter.ReportName = "Build " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
 _klovReporter.KlovUrl = "http://localhost:27017";
 _extentReport.AttachReporter(_klovReporter);
```

I'm using Mongo DB v3.2 and it is up and listening on port 27017 and I'm creating few tests using ExtentTest and logging in it.

```
_currentTest = _extentReport.CreateTest("testName");
_currentTest.Log(Status.Pass, messageToLog);
```

After I flush the report, where do I find the kolv report? Also when I hit http://localhost:27017/ on the browser, it shows like **It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.**
Did I miss any configuration pieces of stuff?

Comment: I'm working on c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Klov's default settings point to port 80.  Try http://localhost if you are running the server on the same box as mongodb.

Comment: in my local system port- 80 is used by other services. i just assigned klov's port as 8010 in application.properties file. And then, everything worked fine

Comment: what is the purpose of file.storage.location=./upload/reports/ in **application.properties** i did't find any folders inside my project or mongoDB folders @Anshoo

Comment: This is where the file uploads (screenshots) are stored.

Comment: Fine. Also, in which location build-wise reports are getting stored in klov-reporter @Anshoo

Comment: What do you mean? Klov does not store any data. Its stored in Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

change the port server to 90 in application.properties file:
server.port=90

and then try localhost:90

It should work.